# How to apply a hair particle effect to a specific material

Tags: modeling, materials, particles, hair, effects

Okay, so I'm making an animal character and I want it to have fur by using the hair particle effect, but only in certain areas where I use a specific material.
I've tried to find tutorials on this but most of them start way far ahead from where I am, have something way more specific in mind, or only apply it to the whole object.
I don't want to use any UV wrapping because I don't think I need to in order to do this

Basically I want a material I can apply to certain parts of my object that will make it appear like it has short blue fur without any complicated UV wrapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use weigth painting. Select your object and go to the Data tab (triangle) in the Properties window. There is a section called Vertex Groups. Click the + icon to create a new vertex group and give it a name. Now you can switch from Object Mode to Weight Paint mode and paint the verts where you want your particles to appear. Blue = no particles, red = 100% of particles.
Afterwards go to your Particles tab, scroll down and open the Vertex Groups section. Click next to Density and select the vertex group you just painted.

(can't provide pics right now, sorry)

Comment: okay, that helped... however its only coming out of one side and not exactly in the areas i want it to... I'm using a mirror effect to make the model semitryzed, could that have something to do with it?

Comment: For more accuracy with weight painting you need more geometry. I don't know how high the poly count on your model is, but maybe you need to subdivide (and apply) it a step or two.

And yes, I do think you need to apply your mirror first, then paint the verts and lastly add your hair particles. I'll test it a bit when i get home.